# Completion rates/retention rates and hours spent on avg for adventure/rpg games

Tags: rpg, statistics, adventure-games, demographics, retention

I'm building an adventure/RPG game and would like to understand two main metrics for this genre of game:

- Completion/retention rates
- Hours spent playing per day, or week or month, etc

If demographic data with reasoning is available that would be helpful too.

IGN's [GDC Study](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/03/17/gdc-most-players-donat-finish-games) gave a list of specific titles, such as `Portal - 47%`, but I'm looking for something more genre related.